# Grails 2.4 Spring Websocket SockJs Java Android Client

Tags: android, spring, grails, websocket, sockjs

Has anyone successfully connected from android to a sockJs server?  I have this code from autobahn on the android client:

```
            try {
                mConnection.connect(wsuri, p, new WebSocketHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onOpen() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                       mConnection.sendTextMessage("[\"CONNECT\naccept-version:1.1,1.0\nheart-beat:10000,10000\n\n\\u0000\"]");



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost.");
                    }
                }, options);

                mConnection.sendTextMessage("[\"SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/topic/heartbeat\n\n\u0000\"]");
            } catch (WebSocketException e) {

                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
```

This code connects to the sockJS server under Spring under Grails.  However, the code loss connection after 5 seconds.  I am not sure what I need to do, to tell the sockeJS server I am listening.